# Terraform azurerm custom rbac role gives connection error on role assignment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a custom RBAC role definition and assignment to assign to an app registration.
All resources and the definition create ok but when it goes to execute the azurerm_role_assignment resource I get:

> Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidRoleDefinitionId" Message="The role definition ID 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' is not valid

I'm probably going a bit code blind as I can't see what's wrong, any ideas?

```
resource "random_password" "aad-app-myrbac" {
  length           = 24
  special          = true
  override_special = "@#$%+=_-*&[]{}?!"
}
resource "random_password" "aad-sp-myrbac" {
  length           = 24
  special          = true
  override_special = "@#$%+=_-*&[]{}?!"
}
resource "azuread_application" "myrbac" {
  name                       = "my-app-registration"
  homepage                   = "https://localhost"
  identifier_uris            = [""]
  reply_urls                 = [""]
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = false
}
resource "azuread_application_password" "myrbac" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.myrbac.id
  description           = "myrbac client secret"
  value                 = random_password.aad-app-myrbac.result
  end_date_relative     = "87600h"
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [end_date_relative]
  }
}
resource "azuread_service_principal" "myrbac" {
  application_id = azuread_application.myrbac.application_id
}
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "myrbac" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.myrbac.id
  value                = random_password.aad-sp-myrbac.result
  end_date_relative    = "87600h"
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [end_date_relative]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_definition" "myrbac" {
  name        = "my role definition"
  scope       = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  description = "my role definition"
  permissions {
    actions = [
    "Microsoft.Authorization/permissions/read",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/read",
    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines/*/read",
    "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read",
    "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read",
    "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read"
    ]
    not_actions = []
  }
  assignable_scopes = [data.azurerm_subscription.current.id]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "myrbac" {
  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_id = azurerm_role_definition.myrbac.id
  principal_id       = azuread_service_principal.myrbac.object_id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
```

note code has been sanitised and the total role defs cut down for brevity.

Comment: I think this has happened to me before, what if you try the following:

`scope       = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.id}"`

If it works, I can extend the explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter `role_definition_name` instead of `role_definition_id` and add the `depends_on` like this:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "myrbac" {
  scope              = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = azurerm_role_definition.myrbac.name
  principal_id       = azuread_service_principal.myrbac.object_id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
    depends_on = [azurerm_role_definition.myrbac]
}
```

It will work for you.